# Ionic 4: is there similar bundle optimization like the one we had with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

With ionic 3 I followed similar guide to this one: https://julienrenaux.fr/2017/07/20/optimized-ionic-angular-css-bundle-for-pwas/ and in fact achieved great bundle size reduction (by allowing only one platform style to be bundled + removing unused components code).

**Question**:

- with Ionic 4 changes and lazy loading for components do we get this "for free" now and we do not have to worry about such tricks?

Comment: Have you found anything to reduce the ionic 4 bundle size?

Comment: so for now I just ensured all things I have in my app get lazy loaded and this reduced initial package down compared with my optimized Ionic 3 app. I am using limited CSS (like only one ionic color) and also only one iOS style (even if on Android device CSS platform style remains iOS). Did not find any decent way to reduce further;/